# Can we get chat on SE 2.0 for moderators only before the official release?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I would love the ability to chat with my fellow moderators about mod stuff for the Gaming SE site, but there isn't quite a *private* place for that yet (not counting the Teacher's Lounge, which would have too much noise for that as it's currently supporting *all* SE sites).

Would it be possible to run a beta allowing *only* moderators to the third place in "their" respective sites, where they could create a private room to discuss stuff related to their role?

I think this is quite necessary.

**Edit**: Private Sub-rooms on chat.meta.so for each site, providing access only to moderators on those sites would also be a good solution.

Comment: Failing that, sub-rooms would be nice.

Comment: Sure @mmy, anything that would be private -- I feel the Teacher's Lounge is too full of people for such specific discussion, but the Gaming room is not the place to discuss some things that shouldn't be public

Comment: Being able to at least have our own private rooms, definitely. The Teacher's Lounge is great when you want to talk to all of the moderators and get a general opinion, but having scoped rooms would be even better when it comes to things like discussing flag actions.

Comment: @Grace, I invited you to a room on chat.meta.so :)

Comment: I'll see you in a couple hours, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We definitely want to limit the use of private rooms. 99.9% of our discussions should be in the light. Moderation is a bit different. I don't know what the final position will be with this, but I've created a "gaming" moderator-only room. Let's use it to see if it is a good idea ;p

To pre-empt the question; no we do **not** intend to support widespread private rooms; nor PM or any other similar option. To quote Jeff:

> We don't want private messages because they are hidden and bad things can happen in dark places

Comment: Sure, I think at least every SE site should have 1 private room for mods -- there *is* discussion that should be held privately (but as you say, this is the exception). Thanks!

Comment: *"We don't want private messages..."* Besides, the whole premise of Stack Exchange is to leave artifacts for those who come after.

Comment: @Robert, new moderators would have access to those rooms

Comment: Although this is great, it's a problem that some meta.so moderators are also "normal" users on other sites, and could potentially enter the room and read discussion about flags and user behaviors. Please keep working on the first suggestion (early per-site chat access for mods), the more permanent awesome solution :)